# Image responsive

Tags: html, css

Where do I make the mistake?

This is my code

```html
<div id="logo" style="position: absolute; right: 50px; top:0px;">
  <img src="./images/logo1.png" width="400" height="400" border="0" alt="Logo" />
</div>
```

I want to make the image appear on the right side on the screen. In order to make it responsive i change the width and height to 23% (the original image is 3000 x 3000 px).
It works fine with the size of the image but instead to show up at the above defined position it appears on the left side of the screen. Only when i change width to percent... Why?

Comment: Don't use inline style attributes - they're ancient. Use CSS files. Also, you're missing the closing `</div>` tag, unless you just omitted it here.

Comment: Do you have a reason you have the image positioned absolutely?

Comment: Why not resize your image, you're currently causing your page visitors to download and waste 86% of that image file. Slow and mobile browsers will not appreciate this markup and it's absolutely not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some css

```
        <div id="logo">
        <img src="./images/logo1.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
<style>
#logo {width:400px; position: absolute; right: 50px; top:0px;}
#logo img {width:100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: [Please read this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340872/image-responsive#comment83667010_48340872)

Comment: Hi @Martin is ok to use css codes in same page with html I don't use as attributes of course but there is no problem to write css and html in same page

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-responsive{
               display: block;
               max-width: 100%;
               height: auto;
}
.right{
      float:right!important;
}
```

Comment: don't use `!important` unless it's, er, really important